# How to determine if the system is linear or nonlinear

Tags: linear-systems, non-linear

Given a signal

$$y(n)=x(n)\cos(wn)$$

How to determine if the given signal is linear or non linear?

I am getting so confused reading the theory. If someone could help step by step to determine this. It would be great thankyou

Comment: If you double $x(n)$ (or multiply by any other factor), will $y(n)$ scale accordingly?

Comment: @user32113: This is the check for homogeneity. In general one must also check for additivity to make sure that the system is linear.

Answer (score 5):

As Matt L. says you'll need to check for [homogeneity and, possibly, additivity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle)

**Homogeneity**

That test says that if:
$$
y[n] = f(x[n])
$$
then
$$
A \cdot y[n] = f(A \cdot x[n])
$$
for all scalar $A$.

**Additivity**

This test says that if
$$
y_1[n] = f(x_1[n])
$$
and
$$
y_2[n] = f(x_2[n])
$$
then
$$
y_{\rm tot}[n] = f(x_1[n] + x_2[n]) = y_1[n] + y_2[n]
$$

You just need to apply these for your system.

---

I say "possibly" because if the system fails one of these tests, then it will not be linear --- so there is little point testing the second condition.